# Any idea when GPU volumetric rendering will be added?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

Smoke and fire renders with cycles take forever with my CPU, but would be much quicker with GPU... Anyone know when this feature will be added?

Answer (score 2):

It is already there for CUDA GPU's in 2.77 and 2.77a. The other kind of GPU is not yet supported. Read the [blender.org page](https://www.blender.org/features/2-77/) for more on 2.77 and enhanced GPU capabilities.